# Making longer underbraces

Tags: braces

I want to make longer underbraces for a better visualisation of interstimulus intervals.

My code looks like this:

```
$$\bullet \underbrace{{}{}}_{1 sec} \bullet \underbrace{{}{}}_{2 sec} \bullet$$
```

How can I stretct the second underbrace?

Is it possible to use a constant for this instead of something like $\longunderbrace$ ?

I mean, I will be using some other time intervals like 1.4 sec, 1.7 sec.

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: What's an interstimulus interval?

Comment: @Mico In a psychology experiment, a participant gets some stimulus, such as seeing a picture, hearing a sound, getting an electric shock etc. The time between these stimuli is called interstimulus interval. A mouse's reaction to electric shocks can be different for different interstimulus intervals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `\underbrace` has some limitations, as it has a required minimum width to construct all the parts related to the brace (see the first example below). I've created `\interval[<wd>]{<text>}` which sets an `\underbrace` of width `<wd>` relative to some unit of measure. The default measure is `em`s, but you can change this, as presented in the second example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\intmeasure}{em}
\newcommand{\interval}[2][\relax]{%
  \underbrace{\ifx#1\relax
      \rule{2\intmeasure}{0pt}
    \else
      \rule{#1\intmeasure}{0pt}
    \fi}_{\text{#2}}
}
\begin{document}
\[
  \bullet \interval[1]{1 sec} \bullet \interval[2]{2 sec} \bullet
\]

\[
  \renewcommand{\intmeasure}{pt}
  \bullet \interval[50]{1.4 sec} \bullet \interval[60.7143]{1.7 sec} \bullet
\]
\end{document}
```

So, if 1.4 seconds is equivalent to `50pt`, then 1.7 seconds should be `60.7143pt`.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
\[ \underbrace{\hspace{2em}}_{\text{1 sec}} \]
```

Also, don't use  `$$ … $$`: this is plain TeX, and can yield bad vertical spacing.

Not sure what you're after exactly, but for short `\underbrace`s, the `\underbracket` command from `mathtools` often looks nicer, and is customisable.

Comment: Thanks. But 2em should be in braces.

Comment: Right. I should have checked what I typed, as often… Fixed.